# Pandas 'eval' with NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with data in string. These data need to be evaluated and change to numeric.

Let my df be:

```
var_pct var_num
-76*2   14*1000000
-76*2   12*1000000
111*2   29*1000000
47*2    33*1000000
nan     60*1000000

for column in df:
    df[column] =df.eval(df[column],inplace=True)
```

I faced problem for column with 'nan' where the result of eval has length less than the original. How do I make sure the 'nan' will be a '' after eval?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? using `eval` is inherently risky. Is there no way to go back and get your dataframe in another manner in a different format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid `eval`. In this case, I recommend you split into **numeric series** first:

```
df = df.fillna('NaN*NaN')

for col in df.columns:
    df = df.join(df.pop(col).str.split('*', expand=True)\
                   .apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')\
                   .add_prefix(f'{col}_'))

print(df)

   var_pct_0  var_pct_1  var_num_0  var_num_1
0      -76.0        2.0         14    1000000
1      -76.0        2.0         12    1000000
2      111.0        2.0         29    1000000
3       47.0        2.0         33    1000000
4        NaN        NaN         60    1000000
```

Then perform your calculations using vectorised operations:

```
for col in ['var_pct', 'var_num']:
    df[col] = df[f'{col}_0'] * df[f'{col}_1']
```

---

For academic purposes, the approach you are attempting is possible via the top level function [`pd.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.eval.html) together with [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html). But beware, this is just an inefficient Python-level loop.

```
nan = np.nan
df = df.fillna('nan*nan')

df = df.applymap(lambda x: pd.eval(x))

print(df)

   var_pct   var_num
0   -152.0  14000000
1   -152.0  12000000
2    222.0  29000000
3     94.0  33000000
4      NaN  60000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can live with a copied dataframe:

```
def ff(val):
    if 'nan' not in val:
        return eval(val)

df4 = df3.applymap(ff)

print(df4)

   var_pct   var_num
0   -152.0  14000000
1   -152.0  12000000
2    222.0  29000000
3     94.0  33000000
4      NaN  60000000
```

Of course `ff` can be expressed as lambda too:

```
lambda val: eval(val) if 'nan' not in val else val
```