# Pandas apply with eval not giving NAN as result when NAN in column its calculating on

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have to support the ability for user to run any formula against a frame to produce a new column.

I may have a frame that looks like

```
    dim01    dim02   msr01
0   A        25      1.0
1   B        26      5.3
2   C        53      NaN
```

I interpret user code to allow them to run a formula using supported functions/ standard operators / other columns

So a formula might look like SQRT([msr01]*100+7)

I convert the user input to Python syntax so this would evaluate to something like

`formula_str = '(math.sqrt((row.msr01*100)+7))'`

I then apply it to my pandas dataframe like this

`data_frame['msr002'] = data_frame.apply(lambda row: eval(formula_str), axis=1)`

This was working good until I hit data with a NaN in a column used in the calculation. I noticed that when this case happens I get a frame like this in return.

```
    dim01    dim02   msr01   msr02
0   A        25      1.0     10.344
1   B        26      5.3     23.173
2   C        53      NaN     7.342
```

So it appears that the eval is not evaluating the NaN correctly.

I am using a lexer/parser to ensure that the user sent formula isnt dangerous and to convert from everyday user syntax to use python functions and make it work against pandas columns.
Any advice on how to fix this?

Perhaps I should include something in the lambda that looks if any required column is NaN and just hardcode to Nan in that case? But that doesn't seem like the best solution to me.

I did see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53728209/pandas-eval-with-nan) which is similar but didnt think it answered my exact need.

Comment: I realized that the rows that I was expecting to be NaN were getting overridden in a different part of the code this was just a case of losing my mind since I am on a newborns sleep schedule. The code above works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can try with

```
df.msr01.mul(100).add(7)**0.5
Out[716]: 
0    10.34408
1    23.17326
2         NaN
Name: msr01, dtype: float64
```

Also with your original code

```
df.apply(lambda row: eval(formula_str), axis=1)
Out[714]: 
0    10.34408
1    23.17326
2         NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: ran my test after your answer and ran it and noticed it worked, so I looked back at my code and found the piece that was updating it. I am losing my mind! Thanks for the help.